# Expressing a general polynomial such that we may factor out a common term (Taylor series uniquness)

Tags: taylor-expansion

I have been trying to understand a proof for the uniqueness of the Taylor polynomial for quite a long time. There is a single step which I cannot fully grasp. The point is to show $Q_n(x)$ is the taylor polynomial $P_n(x)$ of $f(x)$ around $x=a$.

The proof begins by letting $P_n$ be a Taylor polynomial of order n, and $Q_n$ be any polynomial of order n. Then,

$$R_n(x)=Q_n(x)-P_n(x)=O((x-a)^{n+1})$$

which is fine. Of course, we wish to show that $R_n(x)=0$. They then express $R_n(x)$ as the following:
$$R_n(x)=c_0+c_1(x-a)+c_2(x-a)^2+...+c_n(x-a)^n$$
Again, this is fine. What comes next (which I don´t understand) is they claim if $R_n(x)$ is not zero, there is a smallest coefficient $c_k (k \leq n)$ s.t $c_k\neq 0$, but $c_j=0 $ for  $0\leq j \leq k-1$. By this, they express $R_n$ as
$$R_n(x)=(x-a)^k (c_k+c_{k+1}(x-a)+c_{k+2}(x-a)^2+...+c_n(x-a)^{n-k})$$
Would not this imply that $k=0$?

Any help would be much appriciated!

(The proof is from Adams and Essex Calculus ninth edition)

Comment: As a concrete example, the above is simply saying $$0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 5x^{\color{red}{3}} + 0x^4 + 2x^5 = x^{\color{red}{3}}(5 + 0x + 2x^2).$$ We have $\color{red}{k = 3}$.

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thank you! This was very informative!